# MySQL using two databases in same query. Do not want to combine tables

Tags: mysql, database

New to MySQL, searched for answers, but multiple database questions seem to be all about combining tables, that's not what I'm after.

In new database, I duplicated a table from old database, with most columns but not all.

I need to get customer number from old database where customer name has 'Co.' in their name. This should return 14 or so customers with about 80 rows

I then need to delete all orders in the second database that has those customer numbers.

Is this possible with a subquery? that's where I am stuck right now.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with multiple databases on one query:

Ex:

SELECT database1.col1, database2.col2
 FROM `database1`.`options`, `database2`.`options`
  WHERE `database1`.`option_name`="sort_order"

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a table of SO threads (`threads_table`) from which you need to eliminate duplicates that you have already identified in the `Problem` field of another table (`problem_log`).

```
DELETE FROM `threads_table`
    WHERE `thread_ID` IN 
        (SELECT `Thread_ID` from `problem_log_table` 
        WHERE `Problem`='Duplicate');
```

Edited to add:
Here's one way to do it, if I'm understanding your needs correctly.  (Btw, I've assumed away the added complexity of working with tables it two different databases.)

```
DELETE FROM tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.customer_num IN 
        (SELECT tbl1.customer_num from `tbl1` 
        WHERE tbl1.customer_name LIKE '%Co.%');
```

Comment: So for instance db1.tb1 has columns customer_num, customer_name, col3, col4 AND THEN IN db2.tbl2 it has columns customer_num, order_num, col3, col4. I need to grab customer_num from db1 where customer_name is LIKE '%Co.%' because it's NOT in tbl2. THEN I need to delete all rows from db2 where db2.tbl2.customer_num = db1.tbl1.customer_num. I really am lost here. Not even sure I'm making sense.